# How to use coproc on Mac OS X 11?

Tags: bash, macos, coproc

I'm trying to cross io between two processes and coproc does not seem to be installed in OS X 10.11.x.

I get:
bash: coproc: command not found

My bash version is: GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0)

How can I install coproc?

Comment: How did you start `bash`? You might have a newer version of `bash` installed somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/bash`, but that is the error message you would get if you try to use a coprocess using `/bin/bash` (which is still 3.2.57).

Comment: My terminal starts at bash by running command "bash". 

If is run:/bin/bash --version" I see "GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)"
Then I run "/bin/bash" and then "coproc" and I see "bash: coproc: command not found" 

I did have another bash at /opt/local/bin/bash.  I've renamed it but I still get the not found error, and when I run "which bash" I see "/bin/bash".

Comment: You are trying to use `coproc` with the wrong version of `bash`. If you had run `/opt/local/bin/bash`, you would be using 4.3.42.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @chepner!  The issue was even though I had installed bash 4 in `/opt/local/bin/bash`, my calling script had the `#!/bin/bash -` header.